# LoadBalancer Configuration

Tags: apache, nginx, load-balancing

My setting is here

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name *.amvertising.com;
  location / {
    # needed to forward user's IP address to rails
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    # needed for HTTPS
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_pass http://mysite;
  } #end location
} #end server
```

Now I want to given only

```
server_name *;
```

Is it possible Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want this to be your catch all then use

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    #the rest of the configuration
}
```

Comment: `server_name _;` is surplus.